# Find the area (to three decimal places) bound by 2 equations

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the area (to three decimal places) bounded by $f(x)=x^2e^x$ and $q(x)=4-x^2$

So far I've gotten $x^2(e^x+1)-4=0$
and the two $x$ values that make the equation $0$ are $1.027$ and $-1.86$
next I tried to integrate the function to find the area.

I got $A= \int(4-x^2-x^2e^x)dx= \left[4x-\frac{x^3}{3}-e^x(x^2-2x+2)\right]_{-1.86}^{1.027}$.

when I calculated my answer and it was 9.788. This is wrong b/c here are the choices of answers: (A)7.0 (B)7.676 (C)7.333 (D)7.555

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Your bounds and your indefinite integral are correct. (See [WolframAlpha](http://wolfr.am/1nG2UXK).) So I think the only problem can be with when you plug in numbers at the very end.

Comment: ok I redid it and got the right answer, thanks